# A gap in the proof of uniqueness of functional calculus based on a spectral theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, functional-calculus

This question considers the proof of a fundamental theorem of functional calculus, given in the book *Spectral Theory -
Basic Concepts and Applications* by David Borthwick (Theorem 5.9).

Firstly we have the following version of spectral theorem: Let $A$ be a self-adjoint (unbounded) operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$.

> There exists an at most countable collection of finite Borel measures $(\mu_k)$ on $\mathbb R$ and a isometric linear map $Q:L^2(X,\mu) \to H$, where $(X,\mu)=\bigsqcup_{k}(\mathbb R , \mu_k)$ is the disjoint union of copies of $\mathbb R$, such that
> $$
> Q^{-1}AQ=M_\alpha, \text{Domain}(A)=D(A)=QD(M_\alpha),
> $$
> where $\alpha:X \to \mathbb R$ is given by $\alpha(x)=x$ on each copy of $\mathbb R$ and $M_\alpha$ is the multiplication operator corresponding to $\alpha$ on $L^2(X,\mu)$.

Next we define the functional calculus as $f(A)=Q^{-1} M_{f\circ \alpha} Q$, for a bounded Borel function $f$.

It is then proven in the book that

1. $(fg)(A)=f(A)g(A), f(A)^*=\overline f (A).$
2. $\|f(A)\|\leq \sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}|f(\lambda)|$.
3. If $f_n \to f$ pointwise and $f_n$ is uniformly bounded, then $f_n(A)v \to f(A)v$ for all $v \in H$.

Then it is claimed in the book that if $\Phi_1,\Phi_2$ are two functional calculi (maps $\mathcal B_b(\mathbb R)\to \mathcal L(H)$) satisfying the conditions of the theorem, then $\Phi_1=\Phi_2$, so the functional calculus is unique. However, I find that if we let $\Phi_1 f=f(A)$ and $\Phi_2 f= \overline f (A)$ (overline represents complex conjugate), then $\Phi_1,\Phi_2$ both satisfy the above three points, although they are different. **Am I misunderstanding something here?**

The proof of uniqueness in the book *starts* by saying that (note that this is the very beginning of proof of uniqueness)

> These maps [that is, $\Phi_1,\Phi_2$] agree on linear combinations of the form $\sum_j c_j h_{z_j}$, with $z_j$ strictly complex, by property (c) [that is property 3 above].

I am confused because it appears that $h_{z_j}$ are not defined at this point, so I don't know what it is (I tried a long time to search for what it is back and forth). Also, linear combinations are finite sums, so why property 3 about limits has a role to play? I tried my best to *guess* what $h_{z_j}$ are, and searched for similar proofs, but I still cannot come up with a convincing answer.

**I would be grateful if I can find a reference for this proof or some hints on what $h_{z_j}$ are.**

**Edit** - I think we can add one more property to the list:
4. $\Phi$ is $\mathbb C$-linear.

This rules out the example of $\Phi_2$ I give.

Comment: Conditions 1, 2, and 3 don't seem to establish much of a connection between the functional calculus and $A$. They allow $f(A)=0$ for all $A$. I think the intention was to require that the identity function $f(z)=z$ should give $f(A)=A$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I have thought about this as well - but $f(z)=z$ is not bounded, and the condition require the function to be bounded. I could of course try a $C_c^{\infty}$ cut-off to approximate $f$, but this seems too complicated, because there should be only a small gap in the proof, I think.

Comment: Shouldn't $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ be $\Bbb{C}$-linear?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I think yes. But even with that I cannot guess what $h$ is.

Comment: At least this rules out $\overline{\Phi}$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Yes.

Comment: I expect "by property (c)" to be misplaced and to instead mean that the two functional calculi agree on continuous functions by (c) and thus on bounded measurable functions by density (or so).

Comment: @OlivierBégassat But how to first make sure they agree on continuous functions?

Comment: Because of $\|f(A)\|\leq\|f\|_\infty$ which is your point 2 and a density argument presumably. This is just a guess... A density argument with the Stone-Weierstrass theorem should be applied to the subalgebra spanned by the $h_z$, whatever those are.

Comment: So what are some good guess of what $h_z$ is?

Comment: As noted above, you need one more condition (since the ones given only involve the spectrum of $A$ and not the operator itself).  There are many candidates for a fourth one, for example that if $f$ is the characteristic function of a bounded interval, then $f(A)$ is the corresponding spectral projection of $A$.